# Gauge Animation in Android

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I'm trying to create a gauge/meter/dial animation as part of an application I'm trying to build.

What I'm trying to do is to display the acceleration values that I get via the the sensors on a gauge. Now I'm able to successfully get the values from the sensors but I don't know how to display them as an animated gauge/dial.

I've looked at the frame-by-frame and tweened animations, but they don't suit my needs, because I can't seem to use them to change the animation based on input from the code.

I should be able to display an image for the gauge and an image for the needle and then change the rotation of the needle image according to the values so as to make it look animated but I don't know how to do this.

Is there a way a do what I'm trying to do?
Is there a better/alternate way?

---

I'm using the standard Android SDK and eclipse and trying to support devices with android v2.2 upwards.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Ayos  Draw the background, a solid color is best, then draw you indicator in a different color (black). When you get a new value, test to see if its different and if it is draw the indicator in the background color (erase it). Then draw the new indicator.  You will need to figure out a way of scaling your raw data and making it in to degrees to draw the indicator.  Its best if your difference test allows you to not change the indicator if the change does not move the indicator less that a degree or two.  If you use an image or pattern for the background then you have a big job in erasing the indicator.  You might have to redraw the background every time, that takes a lot of processing time and the gauge may look jumpy.  Cliff